# What is the best way to check if the last rows of a pandas dataframe meet a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got stuck trying to create a new column that is a check column based on the 'signal' column. If the last five rows(including the last) are 1, it would return 1, If the last five rows(including the last) are 0, it would return 0, everything else would be the last value of check, like this:

I have the following data frame:

```
       signal
index        
0           1
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           1
6           0
7           0
8           0
9           0
10          0
11          0
12          0
13          1
14          0
15          1
16          1
17          1
18          1
19          1
```

I'd like something like this:

```
       signal  check
index                
0           1       1
1           1       1
2           1       1
3           1       1
4           1       1
5           1       1
6           0       1
7           0       1
8           0       1
9           0       1
10          0       0
11          0       0
12          0       0
13          1       0
14          0       0
15          1       0
16          1       0
17          1       0
18          1       0
19          1       1
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't your check column simply the signal column shifted down by 4 rows?

Comment: No, it isn't. Because I can have "1", right after 0 and 1 again, and so on! I edited the question in order not to confuse people! Thank you!

Comment: The criteria are: 1) if the last 5 rows are 1 the check will be 1. 2) If the last 5 rows are 0 the check will be 0, anything besides that will be the last value of check! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `rolling.sum` to slice `df` and `ffill`, `bfill`

```
df['check'] = df[df.rolling(5).sum().isin([0, 5])].ffill().bfill()

Out[540]:
       signal  check
index
0           1    1.0
1           1    1.0
2           1    1.0
3           1    1.0
4           1    1.0
5           1    1.0
6           0    1.0
7           0    1.0
8           0    1.0
9           0    1.0
10          0    0.0
11          0    0.0
12          0    0.0
13          1    0.0
14          0    0.0
15          1    0.0
16          1    0.0
17          1    0.0
18          1    0.0
19          1    1.0
```

If you want `check` as integer, just chain addition `astype(int)`

```
df['check'] = df[df.rolling(5).sum().isin([0, 5])].ffill().bfill().astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a rolling window over your dataframe, followed by `fillna`:

```
def allSame(x):
    if (x == 1).all():
        return 1.0
    elif (x == 0).all():
        return 0.0
    else:
        return np.nan

df['signal'] = df.rolling(5).apply(allSame, raw=False).fillna(method="ffill")
```

`rolling` returns a rolling window object over a number of elements (5 in this case). The window object is similar to a dataframe, but instead of having rows it has windows over the original dataframe's rows. We can use its `apply` method to convert each rolling window to a value, converting the rolling window object to a dataframe. The `apply` method takes a function that can convert from an ndarray to an appropriate output value.

Here we pass to `apply` a function that returns 1 or 0 if the 5 rows in the window are all 1 or 0 respectively, and otherwise returns NaN. As a result we get a new dataframe with values that are either 1, 0, or NaN. We then use `fillna` on this dataframe to overwrite the NaN values with the first preceeding 1 or 0 value. Finally, we merge the resulting dataframe back into the original dataframe, creating the "signal" column.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Your solution is an `and` on last 5 values. If I uderstand correctly OP wanted the `check` column to retain the value until the opposite criteria is met.

Comment: @DCzo You're right, I misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer to match what OP wanted.

Comment: Concise, yet meaningful. Nice one :)

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Thank you for your help!